# When I removing markers from Here map, do I need to remove handlers?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm using here map api, javascript. I have Map with dynamically created markers. Every time marker added I adding eventListener to each marker. The question: when I removing the marker from map, do I need to remove manually eventListeners from the marker?

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, it's hard to be sure.  What happens if you don't, any problems?  I don't know about the Here API, but typically you don't have to. On the other hand, there's a handy [removeEventListener](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-marker.html#h-map-marker__removeeventlistener) method you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, because removing a marker won't remove the attached event listener. Therefore, if you don't take care of the listener, you will likely end up with a memory leak.

That said, it would be better to have only one event listener for all the markers. You can attach this single listener on the map, or on the clustering provider if you are using clustering.